# Save text data file separated by comma (x,y) into array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have code that will allow user to select txt file to read and pass the number of rows to the plot graph function:

```
private void Load_data_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stream myStream = null;
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\\DataArray";
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
    openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                using (myStream)
                {
                    string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                    var lineCount = 0;
                    using (var reader = File.OpenText(@filename))
                    {
                        while (reader.ReadLine() != null)
                        {
                            lineCount++;
                        }
                    }
                    var lines = lineCount;
                    ShowGraphData(lines);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

the function then receive the number of rows as lTotalData:

```
public void ShowGraphData(long lTotalData)
{
    double[] dx = new double[lTotalData];
    double[] dy = new double[lTotalData];

    for (long li = 0; li < lTotalData; li++)
    {
        dx[li] = GlobalDataClass.dDataArray[li, 0];
        dy[li] = GlobalDataClass.dDataArray[li, 1];
    }
```

my text data will be like:
1,0
1,1
2,1
2,2

My question is how to do like:
the for loop will loop the rows and retrieve the data ex:
dx[0,0] = 1
dy[0,1] = 0   and so on....

and save it in the dx,dy array:

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

I would use an *Array of arrays* instead of two arrays(`dx`,`dy`)

```
double[][] d = File.ReadLines(filename)
                   .Select(x => Array.ConvertAll(x.Split(','), n => double.Parse(n)))
                   .ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(d[0][1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
 var numbers = File.ReadLines("path")
                   .SelectMany(x => x.Split(','))
                   .Select(x => Convert.ToDouble(x))
                   .ToList();

 double[] dx = new double[numbers.Count];
 double[] dy = new double[numbers.Count];

 for (long li = 0; li < numbers.Count; li+=2)
 {
        dx[li] = numbers[li];
        dy[li] = numbers[li +1];

 }
```